# Main domain hosted on Google servers and registered with Google domains, but I want a subdomain ONLY to point to Netlify

Tags: domains, subdomain, google-domains, netlify

Been trying to this for a few days after countless tutorials and I can’t seem to figure it out.

The desired outcome is this:

`www.example.com` is my main react app hosted on Google Cloud Servers.

`blog.example.com` is my Gatsby blog hosted on Netlify.

More Detail:

I have a robust react app that is hosted on `www.example.com`, on a Google cloud server. The domain is registered with Google domains.

I want to add a new subdomain, `blog.example.com` and have it point to Netlify, where I host a simple Gatsby blog.

Everything I find always leads me to change my apex/main domain to netlify servers, but this is not the desired outcome as it will no longer point to my main app, and the email accounts associated with it stop working as well.

I have no idea how to do it.

From my understanding, we can add an `A` record on Google domains:

```
blog.example.com A 1.2.3.4
```

or add a `CNAME`:

```
blog CNAME → theNetlify-app-name.netlify.app
```

Neither of these solutions seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your theory is correct. Im not sure we can help you find what is not working unless you provide the actusl domain (ideally with the a or cname record set up.) It coukd be you are acting on the wrong servers, or conceivably a caching issue.

Comment: So upon changing those DNS settings for the subdomain, it now leads to a 404. 

On netlify's end, I added a domain (blog.mysite.com) and it is telling my DNS nameservers are not configured, and to add them to my domain provider, which ultimately will accomplish something I do not want. 

I'd share the actual domain but currently, it is undergoing a pilot test so it's private.

Comment: Have you configured your Netlify blog with the subdomain host domain that you are pointing at it?   A 404 error usually indicates that the DNS is pointing to the server but that the server doesn't know which blog to show when it gets requests for that name. Netlify has documentation for [custom domains](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/) including how to configure [subdomains through external DNS](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CName to map your desired sub domain to your Netlify site as per their documentation:

[Mapping an existing sub-domain](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/#configure-a-subdomain)

The important thing is that both ends (Google Domains and Netlify) need to know about the new domain.

In summary you need to configure your external DNS provider to point your domain to Netlify:

On your Netlify control panel, select the "Custom domains" panel, select "Check DNS configuration" next to the custom domain to open customized details about the DNS records you need to configure.

To point a subdomain such as `blog.petsofnetlify.com` to your site on Netlify, you must first create a CNAME record with your DNS provider.

For example, if your site’s domain is `blog.petsofnetlify.com` and your Netlify subdomain is `brave-curie-671954.netlify.app`:

- Find your DNS provider’s DNS record settings for your apex domain, `petsofnetlify.com`.
- Add a CNAME record with your subdomain, `blog`, as the host.
- Point the record to your Netlify subdomain, `brave-curie-671954.netlify.app`.
- Save your settings. It may take a full day for the settings to propagate across the global Domain Name System.

Once you've completed those steps with Google Domains, you then need to complete the steps in the Netlify control panel to [assign the custom domain](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/#assign-a-domain-to-a-site) to your site:

Select "Add custom domain" at the bottom of the "Custom domains" panel, and enter your domain name. Select "Verify".

Pressing verify will check that the DNS settings you've entered in Google Domains are correctly configured and pointing at the Netlify site - if they are, then your new domain should be configured and serving pages as expected.